# Updating State at the end of every second

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Say you have this bit of code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("This should run at the end of every second");
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

This will console log something every second, but I want it to log at end of every second (say it begins running at 300 milliseconds into the current second, I want it to take 700 milliseconds to run the first time and 1000 milliseconds every subsequent time). How could this be done?

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` *already* have about a 4-5ms ***minimal*** delay between time/interval expiration and the callback being called. This is the minimum delay! The *actual* delay could likely be more. In addition to this, the console runs in a separate thread from the "main" thread your app is running in, so there are sometimes delays between when you call `console.log` and when the output is flushed to the console. If you are needing more accurate timing don't use any of these.

Comment: What could I do instead?

Comment: It sort of really depends on the specific use case. If you are just wanting to console log state once per second then what you have is sufficient in my opinion.

Comment: What I'm actually looking to do is update a state variable with a dayjs object at the end of every second. I want to display "X hours, X minutes, X seconds left until {someTime}" using this dayjs state object, and want this to be exact and to the second, hence why I want it to update at the end of every second.

Comment: Whose clock are you synchronizing to? In the grand scheme of your app running is being within 1 second "good enough"? Is being within a few tens of milliseconds "good enough"? The React component lifecycle is around 17ms minimum, is that "accurate enough"? Do you see where this is leading? I think you are really asking 2 questions here. (1) you obviously want to run some logic on *about* a "1 second interval", and (2) with this interval you want to apply some logic against some *exact* timestamps. You are asking for help with (2). I think Brent's answer below is a good place to start.

Comment: And I'd argue, based on your previous comment, that if you are actually just making a countdown component that using the interval is very likely sufficient enough. This isn't the Great White Buffalo you care to hunt for.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using setTimeout() or setInterval(). They cannot be trusted, there are no accuracy guarantees for them. They are allowed to lag arbitrarily, and they do not keep a constant pace but tend to drift (as you have observed).

Use the Date object instead to get the (millisecond-)accurate, current time. Then base your logic on the current time value, instead of counting how often your callback has been executed.

Comment: Would I be able to create a state change using a Date object? If so, how?

Comment: You could create a state object specifically for it. Like `const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState( new Date())`  and in your interval add `setCurentTime(new Date())` which would trigger a state change